# Second derivative of $f(x)=\max(0,x-c)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, stochastic-calculus

I am unable to prove the claim that $f''(x)=1$ if $x=c$, and $f''(x)=0$ otherwise.

Let $f(x)=\max(0,x-c)$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ given. By definition, $f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$. If $x<c$, each term in the numerator is $0$ for small $h$. If $x=c$, the numerator is $h$, so the limit is $0$. If $x>c$, the numerator is $0$.

Clearly I'm missing something. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Context of the question is the exposition of Dupire's formula in Bergomi's *Stochastic Volatility Modeling*, page 27:
[image]

Comment: The function $f$ is not differentiable at $x=c$ , hence is not twice differentiable. For $x<c$ we have $f(x) = 0$ so $f''(x) = 0$ and for $x>c$ we have $f(x) = x-c$ so $f''(x) = 0$.

Comment: you are missing the definition of the second derivative.

Comment: Draw a picture of the graph of that function.

Comment: $\max (x,y) = \dfrac{x + y + |y-x|}{2}$ so $\max (0,x-c) = \dfrac{x-c + |x-c|}{2}$

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Are you missing a comment like "... in the sense of a distribution."?

Comment: JonathanZ, the book is written by somebody (Bergomi) who knows that the Dirac delta function is to be interpreted in the sense of a distribution, but it is not a book on mathematics, it is a book on stochastic volatility modelling - he does not explain such details, it is assumed the reader knows them. Obviously, it is not a book for undergraduates.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative is the Dirac delta 'function', which is not actually a function - that explains why you are stuck! When calculating the Dupire local volatility the only property of the Dirac delta function that you need to know is that

$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \delta(S_T - K) \sigma_T^2 S_T^2 \right] = \frac{1}{2} K^2 \mathbb{E} \left[ \delta(S_T-K) \sigma_T^2 \right]$

You may also find it helpful to note that

$ \sigma^2_{\text{LV}}(t,s) := \mathbb{E} \left[ \sigma_t^2 | S_t = s \right ] = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \sigma_t^2 \delta(S_t-s) \right ]}{\mathbb{E} \left[ \delta(S_t-s \right ] }$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}f(x)~&:=~\max(0,x-c)~=~(x-c)
^+,\cr
f^{\prime}(x)~&=~\theta(x-c),\cr 
f^{\prime\prime}(x)~&=~\delta(x-c).\end{align} $$